# Javascript cookies do not function

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

So guys, I try to make this work. When I click on a button on a page, it has to transfer the array to another page to show it. My functions addProduct, showProduct, addItem and button work. But My data from the array does not get passed to the other page. So when I click on a button in page A, a value is added to this array. But on page B it shows that the array is empty

```
var products = new Array();

    window.addEventListener("load", loadPage, false);
    window.addEventListener("load", addButton, false);
    window.addEventListener("load", showProducts, false);

    function addButton() {
        var button = document.getElementById("sell");
        button.addEventListener("click", addItem, false);
    }

    function loadPage(){
        getCookie();
    }

    function getCookie(){
        var elements = document.cookie.split('=');
        var products_cookie = elements[1].split('%');
        for(var i=0;i < products_cookie.length-1;i++) {
            var tmp = products_cookie[i].split('$');
            addProduct(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]);
        }
    }

    function setCookie(){

        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(2592000)); //expire time = 30 dagen nadat cookie aangemaakt is
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString()
        var text = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
            text+= products[i][0] + "$" + products[i][1] + "$" + products[i][2] +"%";  // slaat naam $ aantal $ prijs op
        }
        document.cookie = "tradepoint"+text+expires;
    }

    function addProduct(pName, pAmount, pPrice){
            var product = new Array(pName, parseInt(pAmount), pPrice);
            products[products.length] = product;   
        setCookie();
    }

    function addItem(){
        addProduct("andrej", 2, 1);
        alert(products + " " + products.length);
    }

    function showProducts(){
        if (products.length != 0){
            document.getElementById("shopList").innerHTML = "<ul><li>Full</li></ul>";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("shopList").innerHTML = "<ul><li>Empty</li></ul>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: ***What*** is the problem with the cookies?

Comment: My data from the array does not get passed to the other page. So when I click on a button in page A, a value is added to this array. But on page B it shows that the array is empty.

Comment: You surely can debug whether the cookie is set right. So which function does not work, `setCookie` or `getCookie`? Have you tried one of the many cookie-handling libraries instead of your selfmade functions, which seem to rely on the appearance of exactly one cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are represented as `name=value` pairs, your `setCookie` function doesn't do that you should have `document.cookie = "tradepoint="+text+expires;` notice the = sign.
Also your `getCookie` function may not work if there are other cookies being set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this against localhost? Cookies will not "stick" to TLDs. You need at least x.y.z - use an alias to 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file to test cookie related code.

(stackoverflow won't let me post an url to localhost - anti-trolling technology I presume!)

Comment: I'm testing this on my webhost